# Sencha touch charts: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-charts

In my app, I am trying to create a gauge chart. I am using the follwing code lifted from try.sencha.com:

```
var chartgx = new Ext.chart.SpaceFillingChart({
                                    series: [{
                                        type: 'gauge',
                                        minimum: 100,
                                        maximum: 800,
                                        value: 400,
                                        donut: 30,
                                        colors: ["#115fa6", "lightgrey"]
                                    }]
                                });
```

app.js includes `'Ext.chart.SpaceFillingChart',`

the app crashes and console.log shows me:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Series.js?_dc=1395313495296:403
>   Ext.define.updateStore Series.js?_dc=1395313495296:403
>   Ext.define.updateChart Series.js?_dc=1395313495296:664
>   setter sencha-touch.js:5553
>   (anonymous function) sencha-touch.js:5578
>   Ext.define.getStore Series.js?_dc=1395313495296:396
>   Ext.define.processData Series.js?_dc=1395313495296:609
>   Ext.define.updateHidden Series.js?_dc=1395313495296:904
>   setter sencha-touch.js:5553
>   Base.implement.initConfig sencha-touch.js:4982
>   Ext.define.constructor Observable.js?_dc=1395313489290:96
>   Ext.define.constructor Series.js?_dc=1395313495296:388
>   Base.implement.callParent sencha-touch.js:4718
>   Ext.define.constructor Gauge.js?_dc=1395313495276:100
>   Class sencha-touch.js:5270
>   (anonymous function) VM17961:3
>   Ext.ClassManager.instantiate sencha-touch.js:7011
>   (anonymous function) sencha-touch.js:3284
>   Ext.define.applySeries AbstractChart.js?_dc=1395313495165:821
>   setter sencha-touch.js:5544
>   Base.implement.initConfig sencha-touch.js:4982
>   Ext.define.constructor Component.js?_dc=1395313488525:980
>   Base.implement.callParent sencha-touch.js:4718
>   override.constructor Component.js?_dc=1395313488525:2904
>   Base.implement.callParent sencha-touch.js:4718
>   Ext.define.constructor Container.js?_dc=1395313492912:347
>   Base.implement.callOverridden sencha-touch.js:4834
>   override.constructor Container.js?_dc=1395313492912:1553
>   Base.implement.callSuper sencha-touch.js:4797
>   Ext.define.constructor Component.js?_dc=1395313495455:140
>   Base.implement.callSuper sencha-touch.js:4797
>   Ext.define.constructor AbstractChart.js?_dc=1395313495165:626
>   Class sencha-touch.js:5270
>   doCharts doCharts.js:215
>   Ext.Ajax.request.success standardFunctions.js:166
>   Ext.apply.callback sencha-touch.js:10405
>   Ext.define.onComplete Connection.js?_dc=1395313497651:902
>   Ext.define.onStateChange Connection.js?_dc=1395313497651:846
>   (anonymous function)

I am using `Sencha Touch 2.3, Sencha Cmd 4.0.2.67`.

Comment: Are you sure you receive data from Server? And check if the reader is set properly.

Comment: Yes, definitely receiving the data from the server